# How to write "The equation $ x^{2} + 2x + 1 = 0 $ has no solutions over the natural numbers" in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How do we write the following in predicate logic?

> The equation $ x^{2} + 2x + 1 = 0 $ has no solutions over the natural
>   numbers.

Comment: Depends on the language, and the intended interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \forall x\ (x\in\mathbb N \rightarrow \lnot ( x^2+2x+1 = 0)) \\[12pt]
\text{or } & \lnot\exists x\  (x\in \mathbb N \wedge x^2+2x+1=0)
\end{align}
or other simple variants of these.